# WHMCS Send custom API call after successfull payment

Tags: whmcs

Is there a option to send a custom API call to a domain after a successfull payment or order? I try to register an account to a different platform after the user successfull orders his package.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHMCS gives developers the ability to create several different types of modules using hook points in their application.

See: https://developers.whmcs.com/modules/

Depending on your requirements a developer should be able to develop a module to do just about anything you need, I tend to lean towards using a full fledged "Addon Module" for most of the functionality I need because they are easier to keep track of and manage because you can enable/disable them via the admin UI, you can also get pretty creative with configuration parameters that WHMCS will store in the database for you when using an "Addon Module".

For your specific need the hook you would want to use would be the [AfterShoppingCartCheckout](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/shopping-cart/#aftershoppingcartcheckout) hook

Comment: Great, thank you. I think a addon would be fitting best in my case, because i want to send a api call just when smb buy's a specific product, also it should add a URL button. THX for your answer